# How to add a marker tap/click on map using Flutter/Dart?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I just started to take a look into flutter/dart. Coming from HTML5/Javascript, I wonder what would be an equivalent to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
 placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(location) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location, 
    map: map
});
```

}

I've looked all around the internet, and I found many examples of adding markers, but not on map click.(e.g. [Example 1](https://medium.com/flutter-io/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245), [Example 2](https://medium.com/flutter-io/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245)). The google_maps_flutter plugin doesn't mention anything about this yet. Is it possible to add the marker by tapping the map, or is this something that's still not available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mawg, this question has been answered. See below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/onTap.html) has finally added an `onTap` property for the `GoogleMap` Class.

```
final ArgumentCallback<LatLng> onTap
```

Example:

```
GoogleMap(
    markers: _markers,
    initialCameraPosition: _theSecretLocation,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _controller.complete(controller);
    },
    onTap: _handleTap,
  ),
  ...

 _handleTap(LatLng point) {
setState(() {
  _markers.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(point.toString()),
    position: point,
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
      title: 'I am a marker',
    ),
    icon:
        BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
  ));
});
}
```

Comment: _handleTap takes a parameter but your onTap doesn't pass anything, so how does this work?

Comment: I am not sure what it is called, but that syntax works in dart. or you could also do it like this   ```onTap:(x)=> _handleTap(x),```

Answer (score 1):

```
      List _markers = List.generate(10, (index) {
      Map result = results[index];
      Map location = result["geometry"]["location"];
      LatLng latLngMarker = LatLng(location["lat"], location["lng"]);

      return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("marker$index"),
          position: latLngMarker,
          onTap: () {
                     //Your code here...
                    },
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: result["name"],));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to take the mapcontroller and use it for ex:

```
**GoogleMapController controller;**

**controller.onMarkerTapped.add((Marker marker){/...your code.../);**
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to place a new marker when I click on the map, not trigger an action when I click on a marker.