# How do I set a Map onClick listener for Google Maps in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

I want to place a marker at the latitude and longitude that the user clicks on in my Google Maps Flutter application. Everything I have found so far has been JavaScript or talking about marker on clicks. I need to intercept a click at any point on the map and be able to see its geolocation. Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to add a marker tap/click on map using Flutter/Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262136/how-to-add-a-marker-tap-click-on-map-using-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GoogleMap` provides you `onTap` callback which gives you `LatLng`.

```
GoogleMap(
  onTap: (LatLng latLng) {
    // you have latitude and longitude here 
    var latitude = latLng.latitude;
    var longitude = latLng.longitude;
  },
);
```

Comment: But this only gives the LatLng. what about the POI Place information?? In native Android onPoiCLick() of GoogleMap class directly gives the information of the tapped POI.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh As of now, it only gives you `LatLng`, you might want to look for some packages for getting POI from `LatLng` or maybe fill requesting a feature in `google_maps` package.